# Subscribing to a List of Observables in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a list of formControls. What I want to achieve is to be able to listen to the valueChanges event of any control in this list. For this purpose I tried iterating through the controls and pushing the valueChanges EventEmitter of each controller into a separate list and then using RxJS merge() to subscribe to my list of EventEmitters. Ideally the code within the merge().subscribe() should run if the value for any of the controls is updated. But for some reason the subscription only happens for the first EventEmitter in the list. Please feel free to ask for more information. Attaching code snippets below.

```
getValueChangeObservables(controlsList) {
  const valueChangesObsList = [];
  controlsList.forEach((control) => {
    valueChangesObsList.push(control.valueChanges);
  });
  return valueChangesObsList;
}

subscribeToValueChanges(obsList) {
  merge(...obsList).subscribe((change) => {
    if (change) {
      // should execute if the value of any of the controls change but
      // is only doing so for the first EventEmitter in the list
    }
  });
}
```

I understand you may ask me to simply put the controls in a formGroup and listen to its valueChanges event instead, but due to certain reasons I cannot do so. My problem is essentially being unable to subscribe to all of the EventEmitters in my list of EventEmitters simultaneously.

Edit: Some images for reference.

[image: Contents of obsList]

[image: Contents of controlsList]

Comment: I imagine you have in any place:`this.subscribeToValueChanges(this.getValueChangeObservables(this.form.controls))`, check where you have the instruction if the form has all the controls

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct and would work as intended as

```
const s1=new Subject<string>();
const s2=new Subject<string>();

merge(s1,s2).subscribe(v=>console.log(`Incoming v:${v}`));

s2.next("s2");
s1.next("s1");
s2.next("s3");
s1.next("s4");
```

prints

```
Incoming v:s2
Incoming v:s1
Incoming v:s3
Incoming v:s4
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vigbsl?file=index.ts

I think that you are testing it wrong and you only think it works for the first stream.

double check that your `obsList` is actual what you expect it to be

Comment: I even tried merge(obsList[0], obsList[1]).subscribe if it makes any difference at all even though it really shouldnt but the result is still the same. Does it have something to do with the rest of the EventEmitters going stale for some reason?

Comment: I think that the cause of results you see is different then you think it is and it is a problem with your code - potentially parts you didnt include - and not with rxjs merge

Comment: rxjs merge is simple function and does what it should. I'm sure, that problem ir somewhere else in code that you haven't provided for us. When are you calling `getValueChangeObservables`, with what arguments? The same with `subscribeToValueChanges`. What values ar emitting FormControls, why are you simply ignoring all falsy values with `if (change)`?

Comment: @EdmundsFolkmanis subscribeToValuChanges() is being called immediately after getValueChangeObservables(). As to when Im calling getValueChangeObservables(), if you wish to know what the contents of controlsList are I will attach a SS to the initial post. What I do with if (change) is a separate issue. All I want is for the EventEmitters in my list to be subscribed to simultaneously.

Comment: Looks like you have correctly created an array of FormControls. But how do you know, that control's values are actually changing and each separate FormControl#valueChanges is emitting value? Have you tried to subscribe to only one control and watch for value changes?